# How do I tell Python an object is a list?

Tags: python, function, object, data-structures

I felt real close finalizing a function I had been working on for some time, but there was a problem. I can't seem to be able to communicate with Python that an object I'm passing through a function is a list object.

This is my function: `log(a, b, c)`

My log function is supposed to take a string 'b', and append it to a list 'a' that may or may not exist already, and then take the -1 index of list 'a' (which is the b string) and append it to list 'c'.

I needed mostly more automation out of this function. At the moment, without this function, on a daily basis I have to always code and define 'a' first, then add 'b' to it, append a bunch of stuff, and add a['b'] to c! Way too much work! I need the function to automate that entire process. This is the code I used in my attempt to implement my function:

```
def log(a, b, c):
    try:a
    except NameError: a= None
    if a is None:
                a=list()
                a.append(b)
                c.append(a[-1])

    else:
                a.append(b)
                c.append(a[-1])
```

When I try to use the function, in a case where 'a' is non-existent, Python keeps telling me:

> NameError: Name 'a' is not defined

And that is without quotation marks. If I put quotation marks around the 'a' object, it then tells me:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

basically telling me that Python doesn't understand that the 'a' object is supposed to be a list, not a string (why is talking to computers so hard?).

My function only works if object 'a' ('c' is not a concern because you can consider those a set of lists that are a constant in the program, 'a' is more of a variable because I need a new list everyday) is defined before the runtime of the log().

How can I pass an object through my function, and have Python accept that if it does not exist, it should be a new list object?

People are asking for more code. Like I said in the comments, this is just the test of a function which will be eventually integrated into an existing script, where any value of ‘c’ exists already, but here’s what happens at the prompt:

```
>>>log(“March_25_2018”,{“Log_1”:”Test PMIC tonight.”},Project_Logs)
```

*I’m forced to put March_25_2018 in quotation if it has not been defined before the run of the function. This is the problem; Python handles ‘a’ as a string and not a list. ‘c’ is not a concern, because in the final program, c is always defined anyway.*

```
    >>>Tracback (most recent call last):
   File “<pyshell#73>”, line 1, in <module>
     log(“March_25_2018”,{“Log_1”:”Test PMIC tonight.”},”Project_Logs”)
   File “User_Space/.py”, line 10, in log
   a.append(b)
   AttributeError: ‘str’ object has no attribute ‘append’.
```

Comment: I obviously don't get that, that's why I askd the question. Did you miss the part where I stated I'm having communication issues with the prompt???

Comment: Show us how you use the function. The problem must on the caller side.

Comment: `log` takes 3 parameters named `a`, `b`, and `c`, but those are the *internal* names for whatever arguments you pass. How are you actually *calling* `log`?

Comment: There's no way `a` can not exist inside your function. It's a parameter, which means it exists as a local variable. The `NameError` must come from somewhere else in your code. If you paste the full error with traceback instead of just the first line, and a [mcve] instead of just a fragment of code that may not be the relevant part, we can debug it.

Comment: Meanwhile, the `AttributeError` means that `a` exists but it's a `str` rather than a `list`. Since `a` is a parameter, that means that again the problem is in the calling code—you're doing something like `log(x, y, z)` where `x` is a string.

Comment: `log([], "foo", [])` would work, although it would be pointless because you have no external reference to the lists passed for `a` and `c`.

Comment: @chepner log(January_9th,”I need money!”,Finance_Logs), if a and c exist already, the function runs flawlessly. The string “I need money” will be appended to ‘a’ and ‘c’ appropriately. Specifically, if ‘a’ hasn’t been defined, more importantly as a LIST, the function does not work. Based on the existing code, python will not handle ‘a’ as a string input that needs to be used, don’t quote me on this cause I’m not a programming expert,...used as a call for a new empty list. Don’t know if many are understanding that yet. It’s a simple concept, I feel like I’m only a line of code away.

Comment: Python simply doesn't work that way; you can't pass an undefined name as an argument and have it be autovivified. You either have to pass an existing list, or have `log` *return* a new list that you bind to a name. (`a, c = log(None, "foo", None)`, for example, with `if a is None: a = []` inside the function).

Comment: @abarnert that’s all my code, this function was built outside of the script that it is eventually meant to integrate into, for testing purposes. Not much else to show. I’m forced to put ‘a’ in quotation marks when i run log(). That’s the problem, that’s the big part, nothing else. AttributeError! Python needs to know that, when I pass it the string ‘a’, it has to be used as a variable to a newly created list. Unless there’s away I can pass an undefined object through the function, i.e. no quotation, and python can make a list out of that, I don’t see how that’s not the problem.

Comment: You probably want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: "I'm forced to put 'a' in quotation marks" almost certainly isn't right; it's how you're misinterpreting something else that's happening. Show us the relevant part of the script.

Comment: `log("a", ...)` changes the error you get, but it doesn't get you any closer to defining a name `a` in the current scope. `log` simply *cannot* do that without some hacks that will make your code worse.

Comment: @chepner now we are on the same page! How do I bind the string input ‘a’ to a new list, being that it doesn’t already exist in my program. I probably gottah edit my question, cause I thought what I said and my code made it pretty clear what the problem is . Your right, the question truly is, “How do I get the log(), to bind(or map) the string input of ‘a’, to an empty list, which os created at runtime.”.

Comment: You *don't*. You create a list before you call log, then pass that list as an argument.

Comment: Ok, if your right, that means my function is limited and I should accept that. It is what it is.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: `a` is not an object; it might be a *reference* to an object, *if* you assign a value to the name first.

---

It sounds like you are literally calling your function as

```
log(a, b, c)
```

without first defining what `a`, `b`, and `c` are. You need to do that, with something like

```
a = []
b = "foo"
c = []
log(a, b, c)
```

Note that the names you *see* don't matter; the following behaves the same:

```
some_list = []
my_str = "foo"
some_other_list = []
log(some_list, my_str, some_other_list)
```

The names `a`, `b`, and `c` only exist inside the function, to refer to the values you put in the call.

The function need only be defined as

```
def log(a,b,c):
    a.append(b)
    c.append(a[-1])
```

because part of the contract of the function is that the first and third arguments need to be objects that have an `append` method, and further the first argument has to support `__getitem__`, for `a[-1]` to work (although you could avoid that by just writing `c.append(b)`; after the first line you have the invariant `b == a[-1]`).

There is no way, short of executing `del a`, for `a` not to be defined in the body of `log`, because all named parameters are defined upon entry to the function.

Comment: I hear you, but it’s not working, I’ve tried everything you said. Actually, before I put the “try” method or whatever in my code, your exact code is what I started with. It doesn’t work, the function, or Python, won’t interpret ‘a’ or ‘c’ as anything but strings at runtime, and respond with attribution errors because of the use of the append method. I tried this for hours, up all night, within the function def “a=[]”, doesn’t work, “a=list()” doesn’t work, I’ve tried “try” doesn’t work, used “if clause” doesn’t work, “if-else” doesn’t work, “for” doesn’t work!!!! AttributeError,AttributeError

Comment: Of course not! `"a"` is a string, period. You can't turn it into a list inside `log`. You need to pass a list as the first argument to `log`, creating  it *before* the call if necessary.

Answer (score -3):

This may be because you are trying to use or print the a variable after the function, while a is only a temporary variable inside the function

Comment: I understand that, I’m not printing anything. I’m simply giving the log(), object ‘a’, which is either a list that is defined already, or an input sting which needs to be assigned as the variable to a new empty list.

Comment: @IamPyre You think you are, but you are not.